# Django: How to save mxGraph, so when user refreshes the graph stays? (asynchronous)

Tags: javascript, java, python, django, mxgraph

I convert the current mxGraph the user creates into XML which is stored in the database (ajax.js). I return this in my views as a JSONResponse to my ajax request (views.py).

The data stored in the database saves, as I have checked in the Django administration page and the xml gets updated per save button.

This is all working fine, however the issue is that when I refresh the page the graph created does not stay on the page.

**ajax.js**

```
var button = mxUtils.button('Save', function()
            {
                //var url = "{%url'login'%}"
                //var url = "{% url 'myapp:productdetail' %}";
                //location.href = '/saveData/'
                var encoder = new mxCodec();
                var node = encoder.encode(graph.getModel());
                var xml = mxUtils.getPrettyXml(node); 
                var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

                $.ajax({

                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/saveData/",
                    data: { "xml": xml},
                    headers:{
                        "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        //console.log("data" + data[0])
                        //console.log(graph)
                        //var xmlDoc = data[0]

                        var xmlDoc = mxUtils.parseXml(data[0]);
                        //var xmlDoc = mxUtils.load("/saveData/").getXml();
                        //console.log("xmlDoc " + xmlDoc)
                        var node = xmlDoc.documentElement;
                        //console.log("node " + node)
                        var dec = new mxCodec(node.ownerDocument);
                        //console.log("dec " + dec)
                        //console.log("graph model " + graph.getModel())
                        dec.decode(node, graph.getModel());

                    }
                });
```

**views.py**

```
def saveData(request, user):
if request.method == "POST":
#Get user profile
    member = Member.objects.get(username=user)
#Get XML data once user presses save
#xmlData = request.POST['xml']
    member.data = request.POST['xml']
    member.save()
    print(member.data)
    response = JsonResponse([
        member.data
    ], safe = False);
    #return render(request, 'fastcookapp/index.html', {"xmlData": member.data})
    return HttpResponse(response, content_type="application/json")


return HttpResponse('POST is not used')
```

**models.py**

```
class Member(User):
data = models.TextField(null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

***P.S I have no clue why my JS is not coming in colour, I have added the javascript tag and it's not working... sorry in advance***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create an Ajax GET request and decode the mxGraph as done above.